# K8s node labels with keys and no values

Tags: kubernetes

Sometimes k8s nodes are labelled as `k8s.infra/postgres=` . Is this a valid label for a node ?

How do we use this kind of label whilst adding node affinities in our Deployment manifests ?

```
    spec:
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: k8s.infra/postgres
                operator: Exists
                values:
                - 
                -
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Sometimes k8s nodes are labelled as k8s.infra/postgres= . Is this a valid label for a node?

Yes, it is a valid label. The type the key is a `string` and the value is also a `string` but the value can be empty `string`: `""`.

> How do we use this kind of label whilst adding node affinities in our Deployment manifests?

The operators `Exists` and `DoesNotExist` only use `key:` and not `values:` so you can write:

```
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: k8s.infra/postgres
            operator: Exists
```

Comment: In some cases there are multiple infra nodes and are labelled as ` k8s.infra/postgres-0=`  , `k8s.infra/postgres-1=` respectively. How can we add node affinities in such cases ?

Comment: there is a validation error ```Invalid value: "k8s.infra/postgres-": name part must consist of alphanumeric characters, '-', '_' or '.', and must start and end with an alphanumeric character (e.g. 'MyName',  or 'my.name',  or '123-abc', regex used for validation is '([A-Za-z0-9][-A-Za-z0-9_.]*)?[A-Za-z0-9]')` ``` if i use the `key: k8s.infra/postgres-`

Comment: The label name cannot end with a dash or equal sign.

Comment: does it mean that if we have many nodes with labels like `k8s.infra/postgres-1=` `k8s.infra/postgres-2=` we cannot use one selector to query all of them ? since we cannot have regex in the nodeSelector nor can it end with `-` or `=` etc

Comment: But you dont have that, since a label cannot end with a `=`. Your label name is `k8s.infra/postgres-1`

Comment: thank you Jonas, appreciate your comments, but my nodes are indeed labelled like `k8s.infra/postgres-1=` `k8s.infra/postgres-2=` and i was trying to use a single nodeSelector in my DS to select all these nodes. However, it doesn't seem to work and i end up with using multiple matchExpressions in my nodeSelectorTerms like so,  ```            - matchExpressions:
              - key: k8s.infra/postgres-0
                operator: Exists
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: k8s.infra/postgres-1
                operator: Exists  ```

Comment: *"The operators Exists and **DoesNotExists** only use key: and not values..."* **DoesNotExists** should be **DoesNotExist**